# Как забиндить кнопку Python kivy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Допустим,есть кнопки:

```
    b = Button(text='7',on_press= self.add_number)
    b1 = (Button(text='8',on_press= self.add_number))
    b2 = (Button(text='9',on_press= self.add_number))
```

Как мне сделать так,чтобы при нажатии 7 (кнопка на клавиатуре) нажималась кнопка b и так со всеми?Т.е,чтобы я не ЛКМ нажимал на кнопку,а при определенных клавишах?Хелп.

Answer (score 1):

```
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.clock import Clock


class Test(App):
    def _bind(self, interval):
        Window.bind(on_keyboard=self.events_program)

    def build(self):
        self.button = Button()
        Clock.schedule_once(self.bind, .5)
        return self.button

    def events_program(self, instance, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        self.button.text = str(keycode)

if __name__=='__main__':        
    Test().run()
```

Comment: ,можно пример с биндом семерки, пожалуйста.Не очень понимаю код.

Comment: Что конкретно не понятно?

Comment: Не понимаю сути,вот если в tkinter ,то это просто btn.bind('<Button-1>',func),Для чего здесь **kvargs,нельзя ли просто указать кнопку и функцию как в tkinter?

Comment: Нет, нельзя.Хотя это кроссплатформенный фреймворк, но в первую очередь он ориентирован под touch устройства. Что здесь сложного: поймал событие - вызвал нужную функцию.

Comment: пожалуйста,можно пример с 7-ой и объяснением,прошу,нигде ничего не нашел,и никто нормально объяснить не может.

Comment: Как еще нормально объяснить!?! Добавь код, который я привел в свой класс, сделай print в функции events_program, и посмотри, какой код у клавиши '7'.

Comment: Изменил ответ...

Comment: @QqqqSsss, у вас есть функция, которая вызывается на клик по кнопке, вот и вызывайте ту функцию при получении клика через `events_program`

Comment: @Xyanight Вроде бы работает,но как мне сделать чтобы работал Label?Когда вместо Window.bind(on_keyboard=self.events_program) ставлю self.lbl.bind(on_keyboard=self.events_program),то все перестает работать.В чем проблема?

Comment: Проблема в том, что вы не понимаете суть происходящего: в events_program (события программы) отслеживаются ВСЕ события. И что это за странная постановка вопросов -' как мне сделать чтобы работал Label?'... Я ответил на ваш вопрос, для других - создавайте новую тему.

Comment: @Xyanight Да,я не понимаю сути происходящего.Зачем по-вашему мнению мне задавать какие-либо вопросы,если я и так знаю ответ.Я хочу понять как это работает,поэтому  и пытаюсь узнать как можно больше.Вы видите в этом что-то неразумное?